# How to add non-code files to a conda package?

Tags: conda, packaging

How can I add a file that isn't `Python` to my `Conda` package? I've tried using the "outputs" section of the `meta.yaml` as defined in [the docs](https://conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html#specifying-files-to-include-in-output), but couldn't get it working.

What I'm looking for is a way to have my `Conda` install also create something like this:
/my/directory/my_file.yaml

Is this possible?

Comment: You can install the file, but not in any folder you like: it has to be in the directory that is the physical location of your environment.

Comment: @cel That could work for me - do you know how to do that?

Comment: You would do that in the [build script](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/build-scripts.html). There you create a new folder under `$PREFIX/share/<name-of-your-software>` and copy the file here (unix) or `%LIBRARY_PREFIX%\share\<name-of-your-software>` (windows). Those files will be installed with the package.